# How to connect TI - CC1101 to NodeMCU Board

Tags: nodemcu, arduino-esp8266

I'm trying to get the TI-CC1101 433 MHz Transceiver Module to work with my NodeMCU ESP8266 but I am not sure about the wiring.

Link to the data sheet: [LINK](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cc1101.pdf)

Heres is a link with picture:[LINK](https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/CC1101-MODULE-TI-CC1101-433Mhz-Wireless_60744169613.html)

I only want to use this Transceiver as a receiver for now so that's my setup:

- NodeMCU 3.3 Volt --> VIC of TI-CC110
- GND --> GND
- NodeMCU D4 (2 in Arduino IDE) --> SI pin of TI-CC110.

I tested the following code with another 433 MHz receiving unit and it worked. 
It's the example code of the RC Link Library:

```
#include <RCSwitch.h>

RCSwitch mySwitch = RCSwitch();

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  mySwitch.enableReceive(2);  // Receiver on interrupt 0 => that is pin #2
}

void loop() {
  if (mySwitch.available()) {

    int value = mySwitch.getReceivedValue();

if (value == 0) {
  Serial.print("Unknown encoding");
} else {
  Serial.print("Received ");
  Serial.print( mySwitch.getReceivedValue() );
  Serial.print(" / ");
  Serial.print( mySwitch.getReceivedBitlength() );
  Serial.print("bit ");
  Serial.print("Protocol: ");
  Serial.println( mySwitch.getReceivedProtocol() );
}

mySwitch.resetAvailable();
  }
}
```

I get nothing when I'm trying the new module wired the way described above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello the rc switch library does not support the cc1101 module officially. but there is an external driver library which allows to use the cc1101 module with rcswitch. Currently the esp modules are not supported. an update for esp is in planning.
https://github.com/LSatan/RCSwitch-CC1101-Driver-Lib